# Retrieving data from the MySQL database using PHP - time management

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I need help on how to get/display some informations from DB (MySQl)

My current table looks like this:

```
id | title | level | start_afterID | days | 

1  |   A   |   0   |       0       |   7  |
2  |   B   |   1   |       1       |   5  |
3  |   C   |   1   |       2       |   3  |
4  |   D   |   1   |       3       |   2  |
5  |   E   |   1   |       4       |   2  |
6  |   F   |   1   |       3       |   6  |
```

Level '0' means that this job will start first and start day and time is in other table (`$config_start`)

All others entry with level = 1 don't have fixed start, just `id` of job (`start_afterID`) after which they start.

Also every job will last in number of days from DAYS field.

In this table job with ID 6 (title F) must start after jobID 3 - And that start time is something like:

```
$config_start + jobID 3 + jobID 2;
```

$end of this job is:

```
$config_start + jobID 3 + jobID 2 + 6;
```

At the end, I will need to display all jobs from DB in incoming order.

I tried my best with this, but i can't figure how to check all parent levels and calculate it. 
Also, I can create new administration for this and maybe there is a better way of inserting new jobs ?

**THANKS for any help on this,**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I advise you to rethink the `level` column - IIUC this is only a boolea, telling you wether this is a job root or not - this information is also prsent in start_afterID being 0.

Now calculating the start and end times is a non-trivial job, that requires lots of DB avvess, so I advise you to create a second table with `id|startday|endday` and move the calculation logic in a way, that this (essentially cache) table is updated on job change, leaving you with a fast query path for normal operations.

To calculate the contents of this timing table, you would do something like

```
function docalc($after,$startday) {

    $sql="SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE start_afterID=$after";

    //Run the query, this depends on your framework used

    //Pseudocode from here - again depends on your framework
    foreach ($row) {
        $id=$row['id'];
        $endday=$startday+$row['days']; //This will not be a simple addition, depending on your data types

        //Adapt the following to your data types
        $sql="REPLACE INTO timingcache SET id=$id, startday=$startday, endday=$endday";
        //Run the query - depends on your framework

        docalc($id,$endday);

    } //for each row

}


//this assumes $config_start is set correctly
docalc(0,$config_start);
```

Comment: Yes, I agree with you about removing LEVEL column, and use $config_start + days for starting point for others jobs ...

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you want to sort your data by `level`, `start_afterID` and `days`.

In that case you have to do a select: `select * from table order by level asc, start_afterID asc, days desc;`

Comment: it's not sort problem, I need to calculate start of every job based on parent jobs end, which is also calculated by the same logic, but thanks for help

Comment: I created script that run trough all rows and update new start and new end based on parent job, so every time something is changed, this job recreate all dates ...